# Duda con funciones en javascript, react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

porque cuando pongo una función de esta manera,el `this.state`, no me esta trayendo los valores que le paso cuando escribo en los input

```
fnLogin(event){
        debugger;
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState(obtenerToken(this.state)); // this.state es marcado como undefined
        this.props.fnSetToken(this.state.token); 
    }
```

Este es mi  código, cuando escribo en los input, cada input cuenta con un valor en el state y este se sobrescribe, despues doy click en "NamInputEntrar" para ir a la función fnLogin.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'
import { flogin } from '../Services/usuarios.service';
import './Estilo/Login/index.css';
import { Button , Input, CardImg} from 'reactstrap';
import obtenerToken from '../logic/obtenerToken.js';
import  {connect} from 'react-redux';
import getToken  from '../Redux/Actions.js';

class Login extends Component {  
      constructor(props){
              super(props);

              this.state = {
                redirectToReferrer: false, 
                user : "",
                password : "",
                clickOnButtonEnter: false , 
                token : ""
              };
      }

    fnLogin(event){
        debugger;
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState(obtenerToken(this.state));
        this.props.fnSetToken(this.state.token); 
    }

    handleChangeInputs = (event) => {
        switch(event.target.name){
                  case  "NamInputUser":
                    this.setState({user: event.target.value});
                  break;

                  case  "NamInputPassword":
                    this.setState({password: event.target.value})
                  break;
                  default:
                   ;
                  break;
        }
    }

  render() { 
              const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
              const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state;

              return <div className = "container">
                            <CardImg src={require("./Imagenes/user2-512.png")} className="imgLogo" />
                            <Input type="text" value={this.state.user} onChange={this.handleChangeInputs} name = "NamInputUser" className = "NamInputUsuario" placeholder = "Usuario" />
                            <Input type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChangeInputs} name = "NamInputPassword"  className = "NamInputPassword"   placeholder = "Contraseña"/>
                            <Button onClick={this.fnLogin} className  = "NamInputEntrar"   color="primary">Entrar</Button>
                            <Button className = "NamInputRegis" color="secondary">Registrarme</Button>
                   </div>
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Sin embargo, cuando pongo la función con una arrow function esta si accede al state con todos los valores que sobreescribi en los input.

```
 fnLogin = (event) => {   
            debugger;
            event.preventDefault();
            this.setState(obtenerToken(this.state));
            this.props.fnSetToken(this.state.token); 
 }
```

Leí sobre las arrow function,me di cuente que estas no cuentan con su propio contexto, y creo que por esto le es facil acceder a mi objeto state que esta de manera global, ya leí sobre el this y este aquí esta accediendo al objeto actual deberia encontrar el state, con los valores actualizados, pero no se que este pasando.

Saludos, aiudaa!!

Comment: Posible duplicado de [contexto this en function arrow con prototype](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135637/contexto-this-en-function-arrow-con-prototype)

Comment: las arrow function, hacen el enlace del contexto  en donde fue creada , mientras una funcion toma el contexto donde fue llamada

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acabas de tropezar con la gran diferencia entre `function( )` y `( ) => { }`.

1. `function( )` **no almacena su propio `this`**. Este se obtiene al momento de invocarla, **no** al crearla.
2. `( ) => { }` **si almacena su propio `this`**, que se toma del contexto en el que se crea.

Lo anterior se puede ver aquí:

```
var a = {
  nombre: 'nivel1',
  mostrar: function( ) { console.log( this.nombre ); },
  hijo: {
    nombre: 'nivel2',
    mostrar: function( ) { console.log( this.nombre ); }
  }
}

var b = a.hijo.mostrar;

a.mostrar( );
a.hijo.mostrar( );

b( );
```

Salida:

> nivel1
>   nivel2
>   undefined

¿ Porqué al llamar a `b( )` sale `undefined` ? ¿ Acaso no es lo mismo que `a.hijo.mostrar( )` ?

Ahí se observa claramente como el `this` se toma **de la llamada**, no de la función ni del contexto en el que esta se creó.

En cuanto a tu pregunta, tu mismo te has respondido:

1. Usa funciones flecha `( ) => { }`.
2. Usa `function.prototype.bind( )`, lo cual te permite *asignar* un `this` arbitrario a una invocación.

   ```
   function algo( ) { ... }
   var x = 'cucu';
   var b = algo.bind( x );

   b( );
   ```

Comment: @JackNavaRow ¿ Que te crees, que solo programo en C/C++ ? ¡ Soy multilenguaje ! :-p

Comment: @JackNavaRow Si, bueno. Preguntas como esta suelen salir de vez en cuando. No suelo responderlas, pero es que estoy aburrido :-)

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta bien entendida tu explicación.

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto, por parte de react js, solo agregue al contstructor esta declaración

Comment: this.fnLogin = this.fnLogin.bind();

Comment: Pero me quede intrigado con el punto 2. podrías recomendarme  alguna lectura para ponerme al tiro con este tema.

Comment: Saludos! @JackNavaRow

Comment: @FranciscoMS380 ¿ Para [`bind( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind) ? En general, para JS, nada como la [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/) :-)

Comment: o bien, gracias!!, pues echare una leída para andar al 100, gracias por tomarse el tiempo de contestar @Trauma.