# Duda acerca de this en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo entendido que this hace referencia al objeto propietario del contexto de ejecucion desde donde se usa.

Aprendi que el valor de this cambia en dependencia de si estas en el metodo de un objeto o si estas en una funcion meramente declarada en el ambito global

```js
function fun_global(){
 this.global = "Elliot Williamson"
}
fun_global()
console.log(global)

// A diferencia de cuando estoy en un objeto

let objeto = {
  nombre:"John Doe",
  function: function(){
      console.log(this.nombre)
  }
}

objeto.function()
```

**Pero si yo uso una función anidada y hago uso de this, este hace referencia al objeto global y no al objeto que contiene tanto a la función externa como a la interna, ¿Porque ocurre esto? la función interna esta dentro del objeto no?**

Con respecto a eso encontré esta descripción a ese problema

> Un método no puede utilizar funciones internas que la ayuden a hacer su trabajo porque estas no tienen acceso a sus propiedades

¿Porque ocurre esto si la función interna esta dentro del objeto?, bien podría acceder a esos atributos por estar globales a ella no ?

**Probe a acceder al miembro llamado atributo y el resultado al imprimirlo fue undefined, no debería de mandarme un mensaje de error de que no existe al no poder acceder a la propiedad del objeto por ser función interna?**

```js
let objeto4 = {  
  atributo: "Elliot",
  metodo2: function(){  (function(){console.log(this.atributo)})() }
}

objeto4.metodo2() //undefined
```

**¿Porque ocurre eso?**,

Lei de que es un error de diseño del lenguaje, pero no he encontrado exactamente el porque JavaScript se comporta asi en ese caso

Encontré lo siguiente en un ejemplo de internet con la siguiente descripción y me surgió otra pregunta también:

```js
var myApp = function(){

   var name = "World"
   var sayHello = function(){
      console.log("hello, " + this.name)
    }
}

myApp()
```

**La descripción es la siguiente**

> ¿ A donde esta apuntando this en este caso? Como la función no es ahora la propiedad de un objeto this apunta de nuevo al global(window). esto es un error en el diseño del lenguaje ya que, de comportarse como se espera, this debería apuntar a la función contenedora(que no deja de ser su propietaria)

**¿Porque dice que debería referirse a la función contenedora si funcionara correctamente esa parte del lenguaje? Se que las funciones son un objeto pero lo que tienen en sus cuerpos no son considerados atributos de ella, no entiendo muy bien eso de que si funcionara correctamente this debería referirse a la función padre, agradecería si alguien me lo explicara**

Answer (score 5):

Decir que es un error de diseño me parece, cuanto menos, **muy atrevido**.

Javascript es especial en muchos aspectos, y el manejo del contexto es uno de ellos.

Empecemos por lo básico: `this` indica el contexto de ejecución. Si no estamos dentro de ninguna función, el contexto es el objeto global, que en un navegador es el objeto `window` y en NodeJS es el objeto `global`:

```js
console.log(window === this);
```

Qué ocurre cuanto estamos dentro de una función? En este caso tenemos dos variantes: el comportamiento *antiguo* y el comportamiento nuevo o *estricto*:

```js
function testAntiguo() {
  console.log(this === window);
}

function testEstricto() {
  'use strict';
  console.log(this);
}

testAntiguo();
testEstricto();

let objeto = {
 
  metodo: function () {
    testAntiguo();
    testEstricto();
  }
}

objeto.metodo();
```

Como puedes ver, da igual donde estés, en modo estricto siempre es `undefined` y en modo clásico es `window`.

Pero ¿qué pasa si la función es usada como método? Entonces el comportamiento es el siguiente:

```js
'use strict';
const objeto= {
  atributo: 'Esto es un atributo'
}

function test() {
  if (this !== undefined) {
    console.log(this.atributo);
  } else {
    console.log('This es undefined');
  }
}

test();
objeto.metodo = test;
objeto.metodo();
```

Como puedes ver, una función que **es llamada** como método, tiene como contexto el objeto padre. Remarco el *es llamada* porque no importa cómo fue declarada.

Acabamos de ver una manera de cambiar el contexto de una función, pero hay otras:

Toda función es un objeto de la clase Function. Por tanto, tiene a su vez métodos. Veamos cómo cambiar el contexto de una función usándolos:

```js
'use strict';
function miFuncion(param) {
  console.log('Mi contexto es ', this,' y me han pasado el parámetro ',param);
}

miFuncion(0);

let objeto = {s:'Un String'};

miFuncion.call(objeto,1); //El primer parámetro es el contexto

const atada = miFuncion.bind('Otro String'); //Asocio el contexto a la función, da igual cómo la llame
atada(2);

objeto.fn = atada;
objeto.fn(3)
```

Esto vendría a ser lo básico, pero aún nos queda estudiar las funciones flecha, aunque para eso [tenemos esta otra pregunta y respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135637/contexto-this-en-function-arrow-con-prototype), así que no me voy a repetir.