# Complejidad de código por encima de lo aceptable

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, complejidad

Estoy tratando de bajar la complejidad de este código:

```
//!Complejidad 7... Hay que bajarla a 5
app.put("/stock/:id", (req, res) =>
{
  let id = req.params.id
  let datos = req.body
  Articulo.findById(id).exec().then(
  //Complejidad 37
  (articulo) =>
  {

      modificarStock(articulo, datos)
      return articulo.save()

  }).then(
  //Complejidad 11
  (articuloGuardado) =>
  {
    return RESP._200(res, null , [
        { tipo: articulo, datos: articuloGuardado },
    ]);

  } )
  .catch(
   // Complejidad 10
   err =>{
      return RESP._500(res, {
         msj: 'Hubo un error actualizando el stock.',
         err:  err,
     });
  });
})
```

Pero al parecer cada vez que agrego un `return` dentro de la promesa me sube un punto la complejidad para estar dentro de lo aceptable. Como puedo hacer que este código sea menos complejo?

## A tomar en cuenta.

No tengo mucho conocimiento sobre la teoría así que baso esta pregunta en la información que me despliega el plugin de [CodeMetrics](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kisstkondoros.vscode-codemetrics) en **Visual Studio Code**.

Tambien estoy usando `mongoose` en proyecto ya avanzado y es muy costoso hacer el cambio necesario para usar `async` y `await`.

Comment: la  instruccion `.then(

  (articulo) =>
  {

    return modificarStock(articulo, datos)

  }).` esta de mas porque no hacer ninguna operacion ni nada lo ideal seria `.then(
  (articulo) => modificarStock(articulo, datos))` para que haces un arrow function con un return cuando puedes quitar la llave y colocar directo el retorno puedes ver la [caracteristica de arrow function](http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies)

Comment: Excelente dato. Ignoraba que podía hacer algo tan sencillo. Haz una respuesta para aceptarla por favor.

Comment: en la respuesta previa te muestra las caracteristicas adicionales que tienen las funciones de flechas , tambien puedes ver [el contexto this en las funciones de flecha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135637/contexto-this-en-function-arrow-con-prototype)

Comment: @Angel el tip del arrow function bajo la complejidad de tu codigo? como se mide esa complejidad? que tiene que ver una instruccion return inocua en un codigo con la complejidad?

Comment: @gbianchi No tengo mucho conocimiento sobre la teoría así que baso esta pregunta en la información que me despliega el plugin de CodeMetrics in Visual Studio Code. Y si, increiblemente, al quitar los `return` el plugin me devuelve un valor menor en la complejidad. De echo, si creo una función con varios `return` en ella la complejidad se va disparando.

Comment: Fijate que la documentacion de ese medidor de complejidad es bastante ambiguo... Un switch con 4 clausulas ya te da un error de complejidad. Creo que tal vez, este midiendo mal la complejidad. Igual, hubiera sido interesante que la pregunta incluyera toda esa informacion, ya que asi como esta es ambigua, para mi ese algoritmo tiene cero complejidad real.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la solución vendría con el uso de operadores asíncronos `async|await`. Luciría algo así como:

```
app.put("/stock/:id", async (req, res) =>
{
  try {

      let id = req.params.id
      let datos = req.body
      let articulo = await Articulo.findById(id).exec();

      modificarStock(articulo, datos);

      let articuloGuardado = await articulo.save();

      RESP._200(res, null , [
          { tipo: articulo, datos: articuloGuardado },
      ]);

  }catch(err) {

      RESP._500(res, {
          msj: 'Hubo un error actualizando el stock.',
          err:  err,
      });

  }
})
```

Comment: No puedo trabajar de esta manera en mongoose. Me tira este error: `ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel. Document: 5d0e647cd655fd1ce4984587` Aunque la complejidad del plugin si bajo la lectura es mucho mas difícil. Aun asi, no funciona.

Comment: Tiene eso que ver con el control de concurrencias?? Deberia implementar un monitor de peticiones para controlar regiones críticas en caso de ser esa la causa

Comment: No, es mas sencillo, trabajo con promesas y cambiar al uso de `async` y `await` conllevaría adaptar mi codigo.

Comment: Mmmmm, realmente habria que ver mas alla lo que tienes implementado que ocasiona eso, pero te llevaria mas tiempo e imagino que si esto es algo que está en produccion o por salir, no dispongas de mucho

Comment: El uso de los operadores refactoriza lo que llaman "Callback Hell" o "el Infierno de las funciones de retorno"

Comment: Exacto. Es algo que actualmente esta en producción y hacer un cambio de ese tipo me costaría mucho tiempo.