# Pusher - Notificaciones en tiempo real, afectar el modelo en Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, pusher

Despues de varios intentos he recurrido a preguntar algo que posiblemente sea muy identificable por su error.

Implementando notificaciones con [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) me he topado con un problema. No puedo asignar la información de recepción a mi modelo en Vuejs. Actualmente tengo mi código de la siguiente manera:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel.' + this.notificationId);
channel.bind('postulation', function(data) {
        console.log(data)
})
```

Puedo pasarlo sin ningún problema a la consola la recepción de la notificación.
Pero... si quiero
asignar a un modelo, de la siguiente manera:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel.' + this.notificationId);
    channel.bind('postulation', function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            this.notifyCount ++
    })
```

No funciona, de echo, si intento hacer impresión `console.log(this.notifyCount)` me dice `undefined` alguien sabe porque no puedo asignar información a mi modelo?

Cabe decir que solo pasa dentro de `channel.bind()` ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: Intenta usar la funcion de flechas `()=>` de la siguiente manera `channel.bind('postulation', data=> {
            console.log(data)
            this.notifyCount ++
    })`

Comment: @AlbertHidalgo tengo un problema, esta repitiendo la asignación. es decir. Esta pasando doblemente el `++` ¿A qué se debe?

Comment: Tu pregunta se relaciona con [contexto this en function arrow con prototype](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135637/contexto-this-en-function-arrow-con-prototype)

Comment: el .bind() va al final de la funcion, alli le dices cual contexto pasas, por lo que veo le estas pasano un string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema está en la *variable* `this`, que no es lo que tu crees.

### Lo que debes saber acerca de `this`

`this` (alias "el contexto") es un identificador especial dentro de cada función y su valor depende de *cómo* la función es invocada, y no de cómo/donde/cuándo fue definida. No se ve afectada por ámbitos léxicos como otras variables (a excepción de las *funciones de flecha*, ver más abajo). Aquí hay unos ejemplos:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}

// llamada normal 
foo(); // this se referirá a window

// cómo método de un objeto
var obj = {bar: foo};
obj.bar(); // this se referirá a obj

// cómo una función constructor
new foo(); // this se referirá a un objeto que hereda de foo.prototype
```

Para aprender más sobre `this`, echa una mirada a la [documentación MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

---

### Cómo referirse al `this` correcto

#### No uses `this`

En realidad, no deseas acceder a `this` en particular, sino *al objeto al que hace referencia*. Es por eso que una solución fácil es simplemente crear una nueva variable que también se refiera a ese objeto. La variable puede tener cualquier nombre, pero los más comúnmente utilizados son `self` y `that`.

```
function MyConstructor(data, transport) {
    this.data = data;
    var self = this;
    transport.on('data', function() {
        alert(self.data);
    });
}
```

Dado que `self` es una variable normal, obedece las reglas de alcance léxico y es accesible dentro del *callback*. Esto también tiene la ventaja de que puede acceder al valor `this` del propio *callback* (que como ya vimos depende de dónde y cómo se llama la función).

#### Establecer explicitamente el `this` del *callback* - parte 1

Puede parecer que no se tiene control sobre el valor de `this` porque su valor se establece automáticamente, pero ese no es el caso.

Cada función tiene el método [`.bind`*<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), que devuelve una nueva función con `this` vinculado a un valor. La función tiene exactamente el mismo comportamiento que la que llama a `.bind`, solo que `this` ha sido establecido por ti mismo. No importa cómo o cuándo se llama esa función, `this` siempre se referirá al valor que se le pasa.

```
function MyConstructor(data, transport) {
    this.data = data;
    var boundFunction = (function() { // no son necesarios los paréntesis
        alert(this.data);             // pero mejoran la legibilidad
    }).bind(this); // <- aquí llamamos a .bind() y pasamos this
    transport.on('data', boundFunction);
}
```

En este caso, estamos estableciendo el `this` del *callback* al valor del mismo `this` de `MyConstructor`.

**Nota:** Cuando se establece el contexto en jQuery, se utilza [`jQuery.proxy` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) en lugar de `.bind`. La razón de esto es que no se necesita almacenar la referencia a la función cuándo se desvincula el *callback* del evento. `jQuery` maneja esto internamente.

#### ECMAScript 6: Utilizar [funciones de flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

ECMAScript 6 introdujo las *funciones de flecha*, que pueden considerarse como funciones *lambda*. No tienen su propio enlace `this`. En cambio, `this` se busca en la visibilidad al alcance de la función, al igual que una variable normal. Eso significa que no se tiene que llamar a `.bind`. Ese no es el único comportamiento especial que tienen, consulte la documentación de MDN para obtener más información.

```
function MyConstructor(data, transport) {
    this.data = data;
    transport.on('data', () => alert(this.data));
}
```

#### Establecer explicitamente el `this` del callback - parte 2

Algunas funciones/métodos que aceptan *callbacks* también aceptan un valor al que debe referirse `this` dentro del *callback*. Esto es básicamente lo mismo que hacer *bind* uno mismo, pero la función/método lo hace por ti. [`Array#map` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) es un método de este tipo. Su firma es:

```
array.map(callback[, thisArg])
```

El primer argumento es el *callback* y el segundo es el valor al que se referirá `this`. A continuación un pequeño ejemplo:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var obj = {multiplicador: 42};

var new_arr = arr.map(function(v) {
    return v * this.multiplicador;
}, obj); // <- acá pasamos `obj` como segundo argumento
```

**Nota:** Generalmente es la documentación de la función/método la que menciona si se puede pasar o no un valor para `this`. Por ejemplo, el método [`$.ajax` de jQuery *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) describe una opción llamada `context`:

> This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks.

Traducción libre:

> Este objeto será el contexto de todas las llamadas a *callbacks* relacionadas con Ajax.

---

### Problema común: uso de métodos de objeto como *callbacks*/manejadores de eventos

Otra manifestación común de este problema es cuando se utiliza un método de objeto como *callback*/manejador de eventos. Las funciones son ciudadanos de primera clase en JavaScript y el término **método** no es más que un término coloquial para una función que es un valor de una propiedad de objeto. Pero esa función no tiene un enlace específico al "objeto que la contiene".

Considera el siguiente ejemplo:

```
function Foo() {
    this.data = 42,
    document.body.onclick = this.method;
}

Foo.prototype.method = function() {
    console.log(this.data);
};
```

La función `this.method` es asignada como manejador del evento click pero, si se hace clic en `document.body` el valor que aparecerá en el log será `undefined` ya que dentro del manejador de evento `this` se refiere a `document.body`, no a la instancia de `Foo`.

Como ya he mencionado al inicio, lo que se refiere con `this` depende de cómo la función es **llamada** y no de cómo es **definida**.

Si el código fuese como el siguiente, sería más obvio que la función no tiene una referencia implícita hacia el objeto:

```
function method() {
    console.log(this.data);
}


function Foo() {
    this.data = 42,
    document.body.onclick = this.method;
}

Foo.prototype.method = method;
```

**La solución** es la misma que se ha mencionado arriba: Si está disponible, utiliza `.bind` para enlazar de manera explicita `this` a un valor específico.

```
document.body.onclick = this.method.bind(this);
```

O explicitamente llama la función como un "método" del objeto, utilizando una función anónima como *callback*/manejador de evento mientras asignas el objeto (`this`) a otra variable:

```
var self = this;
document.body.onclick = function() {
    self.method();
};
```

O utiliza una función de flecha:

```
document.body.onclick = () => this.method();
```

Con información de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/255257) de StackOverflow en inglés.

Comment: por cierto la informacion de la respuesta en ingles, no se parece a una que tenemos nosotros?? mirala a ver https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135637/contexto-this-en-function-arrow-con-prototype

Comment: bind significa enlazar, por ende, se esta enlazando el contexto que pases alli al this dentro de la funcion

Answer (score 5):

El problema se debe a que si usas `bind` sin indicar el contexto el valor de `this` será `pusher`

### Solución:

Para indicar el contexto debes pasarlo así:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel.' + this.notificationId);
var handler = function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        this.notifyCount ++
};
var context = this;

channel.bind('postulation', handler, context);
```

---

Referencias:

- [EVENTS > Binding with optional `this` context](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/events#binding-with-optional-this-context)