# utilizar variable fuera del fetch

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de hacer que la variable **users** que contiene un array de nombres de usuarios pueda ser utilizada desde fuera del fetch. cuando hago console log dentro del fetch no tengo problema, me aparece la variable con sus nombres en tipo array, el problema es cuando intento mostrar los datos de la variable users fuera del fetch esta me aparece vacia. existe alguna manera de poder utilizar para luego recorrer esa variable fuera del fetch?

```
let sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('sliders');
let contentDots = document.querySelector('.content-dots');
let name = document.getElementsByClassName('.name');



let sliderArray = [];
let users = []; // esta variable no puede ser mostrada fuera del fetch

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
.then(resp => {
    console.log(resp.status);
    return resp.json();
})

.then(data => {
    data.map((persona) => {  
    let nombres = persona.name;
    users.push(nombres);
    })
})


for(i = 0; i < sliders.length; i ++) {
    sliderArray.push(sliders[i]);
}

for(i = 0; i < sliderArray.length; i++) {
    let dots = document.createElement('div');
    dots.className += 'dots';
    contentDots.append(dots);
    console.log(dots);
}
```

Comment: @gbianchi buenisimo intentare mediar la variable con un scope global.

Comment: ¿Tu fetch si te está trayendo los usuarios?

Comment: @farsSharp si si

Comment: Hola, el problema es de sincronía. `fetch` realiza un proceso asíncrono, por lo tanto JS pone dicho proceso en el `event loop` y continúa la ejecución del código que venga después de la llamada a `fetch`. Es por ello que el `console.log` fuera del `fetch` te devuelve en este caso un `array` vacío, ya que el mismo aún no ha sido llenado. Para resolverlo tendrías que implementar tu lógica dentro de la segunda llamada `then` del método `fetch`. Saludos

Comment: Otra opción sería implementar `async/await`, todo va a depender de si realmente necesitas tu variable fuera del ámbito de `fetch` o no. Saludos

Comment: vale amigo @MauricioContreras es que es un slider (lo deje en 3 slides) y en el deben caer los 3 nombres usuarios de esa api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que la sintaxis sea como quieres, la única forma es que **todo** se ejecute dentro de una función `async`, toda vez que usamos el `await` la ejecución se queda esperando:

```js
(async () => {

let users = ['usuario1'];

await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach((persona) => {
      let nombres = persona.name;
      users.push(nombres);
    });
  });

//AQUI SE PUEDE USAR USERS
console.log(users);


})();
```

sino, tienes que usar el `then()`, como otros usuarios sugirieron, otra opción es lanzar una función en el callback:

```js
let users = ['usuario1'];

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach((persona) => {
      let nombres = persona.name;
      users.push(nombres);
    });
    hacerAlgo(); //<-- Aquí users tiene datos nuevos
  });


function hacerAlgo() {
  console.log(users);
}
```

Comment: Siempre y cúando no se tenga que dar soporte a IE será una gran idea utilizar ES6.

Answer (score 1):

Primero cambia la sintaxis de tu fetch y [asginalo a una variable que sí tengo acceso al resto del ambito](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135637/contexto-this-en-function-arrow-con-prototype). Desconozco el resto de tu estructura de tu script; es muy probable que eso juegue con tu variable.

Es por tu ultimo then. Es debido al map que estás aplicando. Recuerda que [map sí hace un loop pero te retorna un arreglo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) de lo que solicites; en ese loop solo lo de tu lista tiene alcance. Por ende, no es necesario hacer el push dentro.

```
var users = () => fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
.then(resp => {
    console.log(resp.status);
    return resp.json();
}).then(data => data.map(persona => persona.name ));

users();
```

Comment: claro @farsSharp comprendo, pero aun no logro hacer que ese array de nombres sea usado en cualquier parte del script

Answer (score 1):

Cuando tenemos una petición fetch esto es una llamada en segundo plano, más conocido como ajax, lo que ocurre en javascript es que el callback de retorno sólo es capturado en el then, lo que se conoce como promesa, este es parte de tú código :

```
let sliderArray = [];
let users = []; // esta variable no puede ser mostrada fuera del fetch

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
.then(resp => {
    console.log(resp.status);
    return resp.json();
})

.then(data => {
    data.map((persona) => {  
    let nombres = persona.name;
    users.push(nombres);
    })
})
```

Lo que ocurre es que se debe encapsular el código con una promesa para llegar a tener esos valores disponibles y a mí parecer tener una visión de cúando se complete la petición entonces haré los otros loops, con información de usersResolved que contendrá los nombres.

```
let sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('sliders');
let contentDots = document.querySelector('.content-dots');
let name = document.getElementsByClassName('.name');
let sliderArray = [];

new Promise(function(res,rej){
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(resp => {
    console.log(resp.status);
    return resp.json();
    }).then(data => {
        let users = [];
    data.map((persona) => {  
    let nombres = persona.name;
    users.push(nombres);
    });
    res(users);
    });
}).then( usersResolved => {

 // Es el array de Users.
 console.dir(usersResolved);

 // Una vez resuelto los nombres de usuario..

  for(i = 0; i < sliders.length; i ++) {
    sliderArray.push(sliders[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < sliderArray.length; i++) {
        let dots = document.createElement('div');
        dots.className += 'dots';
        contentDots.append(dots);
        console.log(dots);
    }

} );
```