# ¿Como guardo lo que me regrese una promesa fetch en una variable?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Tengo una funcion que hace una peticion con fetch a la API de pokemon y quiero guardar la informacion que utilizare del json en un arreglo para despues mostrarlo en HTML en una tabla.
Mi funcion es la siguiente.

```
const baseURL = ()=>{
    let parametro = document.getElementById("pokemon").value;
    let url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + parametro;
    fetch(url)
        .then((response => response.json()))
        .then(myJson => console.log(myJson))
}
```

Quiero poder manipular la data afuera del .then y posteriormente agregarla a un arreglo.

Comment: No podrás hacerlo fuera del `then`, a menos que todo tu código lo ejecutes en un entorno `async` y uses `await` para obtener las respuestas. Toma en cuenta que de hacerlo así, tampoco podrás sacar esa (y ninguna otra) variable fuera del entorno `async`.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [utilizar variable fuera del fetch](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/290825/utilizar-variable-fuera-del-fetch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al llamar fetch ya empiezas a jugar con promesas. Puedes crear una funcion para limpiar el codigo un poco pero sigue siendo casi lo mismo

```
 async function buscaPokemon(parametro) {
   let url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + parametro;
   let response = await fetch(url);
   if (!response.ok) {
     throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
   }

   let myJson = await response.json();

   // Has tus converciones aqui
   let arregloRespuesda = ....
   return arregloRespuesta;
 }

 let parametro = document.getElementById("pokemon").value;
 buscaPokemon(parametro)
 .then((arreglo) => {
   // Aqui pones lo que pasa despues de esta llamada
 })
 .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Aqui te dan bastante informacion sobre estos conceptos
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await